# How to sort list of object in angular in my case

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to user `orderBy` for my `ng-repeat`. However, I have one additional item that I want to add on top of the list. so like

```
Catogary
AItem
BItem
CItem
DItem
```

Category is added to the list after i got the list of my items. I don’t want Category to be filtered and become

```
AItem
BItem
Catogary
CItem
DItem
```

My ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat=“item in items | orderBy:’title’”>
</div>
```

How do I fix this? Thanks!

Sample data

```
$scope.items = [
    {id: ‘aaa’,
     title: ‘AItem’,
     type:’picture’
     },
    {id: ‘bbb’,
     title: ‘BItem’,
     type:’toy’
     },
    {id: ‘ccc’,
     title: ‘CItem’,
     type:’food’
     }
]
```

Comment: Please show sample data . Data shown is meaningless

Comment: What is "orally micro service" and is it in any way related to the question? If not, [edit] your question and remove it.

Comment: And now that data is added to question it's not clear at all what should be on top

Comment: Which part of the code updates `$scope.items` in your controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a plunker demonstrating what Austin is saying to do and solves your problem http://plnkr.co/edit/nkixXUlTXYvwlB388jlA?p=info.

Your controller essentially becomes this.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($filter) {
  var vm = this;

  var data = [{
    id: 'aaa',
    title: 'AItem',
    type: 'picture'
  },
  {
    id: 'ddd',
    title: 'DItem',
    type: 'test'
  },
  {
    id: 'bbb',
    title: 'BItem',
    type: 'toy'
  }, {
    id: 'ccc',
    title: 'CItem',
    type: 'food'
  }];

  vm.items = $filter('orderBy')(data,'title');

  vm.items.unshift({
    id: 'something',
    title: 'Catogary',
    type: 'idk'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the list in the controller, then add the Catogary (Category???) item to the array, then bind that to the view

Comment: but the orderBy will sort the array even if I add Category into the list

Comment: It won't BonJon. You would remove the orderBy filter from your html, inject $filter into your controller and order it there before doing a javascript unshift.

Answer (score 1):

Try to display the category on its own.
Filter out the categories first and then sort.

```
<div ng-repeat=“item in items | filter:{title:'Catogary'}”>
    <!-- display the catogary-item -->
</div>
<div ng-repeat=“item in items | filter:{title:'!Catogary'} | orderBy:'title'”>
    <!-- display other items -->
</div>
```

This actually shouldn't ever be needed. You should think about your data structure.

Comment: This will hide 'Catogary' from the list, I need it to be shown on the top of the list. +1

Comment: answer edited. not the pretty way, though! Also you technically wouldn't need the ng-repeat, if there's only one 'Catogary' to display.